# How can I convert a tileset to an Albers projection? Or add a feature to an albers projection that lines up correctly?

Tags: mapbox

Mapbox studio has a style with an Albers projection (https://www.mapbox.com/elections/albers-usa-projection-style):

[image]

I need to use another style with waterbodies like this:

[image]

but in the Albers projection. When I start with the Albers style, and then add water, they of course don't line up:

[image]

How can I get the tile I used in my waterbody example to be in the Albers project?  I ultimately am wanting to use it in a leaflet map and add markers to it (using R).

Answer (score 1):

The example you cited above is actually showing a workaround to make data appear as if it is projected in Albers but it's really just altered polygons being displayed in webmercator.  This was a workaround/hack to get the desired visual using the tools available at the time.  If you want to do the same workaround for your water bodies data so it will appear this way in leaflet, follow the steps of the tutorial which uses third party tools (QGIS, Dirty Reprojectors, Tippecanoe)

Mapbox has since added support for non-webmercator projections, which means you don't need to modify your source data to reproject them for use in a mapboxgl-js map: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/projections/

Disregard the earlier example, and just change the projection to Albers in Mapbox Studio.

[image: Choosing Albers Projection in Studio]

Bear in mind that changing the projection in Mapbox Studio does not actually modify your data, it just renders it differently on the screen.

Comment: Thanks.  Changing the projection is the first step, is there any way to shift the geometry for Alaska and Hawaii to match the earlier workaround?

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to do this in R: https://rud.is/b/2014/11/16/moving-the-earth-well-alaska-hawaii-with-r/. You can probably do it in QGIS, or perhaps using turfjs, but I wasn't able to find ready-to-follow tutorials on how to accomplish this.

Comment: those are moving polygons, not tilesets.